# On Sylow subgroup of a finite group

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups

Let $p\mid n$, then by $n_p$ we mean the $p$-part of $n$, i.e. $n_p = p^k$ if $p^k\mid n$ but $p^{k+1}\nmid n$. Let $G$ be a finite group, $M\leq G$ and $P\in Syl_p(G)$.  Is It true that $|M\cap P|=|M|_p$? Why?

Comment: What if $M$ is a $p$-group that is not contained in $P$?

Comment: @Jason: In this case we can consider a Sylow $p$-subgroup such that contains $M$ and so this equality is true. So we should consider $M$ is not a $p$-group. What happen in this case? This equality is true again?

Comment: Are you asking whether every Sylow $p$-subgroup of $M$ is contained in *some* Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$?  Since every $p$-subgroup of $G$ is contained in a maximal $p$-subgroup of $G$, this is true.  You can find the statement of the Sylow theorems in algebra textbooks; MO is not the place for this type of question.

Comment: As others have remarked, this is false in general. However, it is true if $M \lhd G$, or more generally, if $M \lhd \lhd G$.

Comment: Let a Sylow p-subgroup is not normal in a p-group G, P and P_1 are distinct Sylow p-subgroups of G. If M is the normalizer of P_1 in G, then |M\cap P|_p<|P|

Answer (score 1):

The answer is NO. The easiest example is given by $G=\mathcal{S}_3$, the symmetric group on three elements. If you take $P=\langle (12)\rangle$, $M=\langle (13)\rangle$ and $p=2$, then $\vert M\cap P\vert_p=1$ but $\vert M\vert_p=2$.